# How do you manipulate the output using json_encode?

Tags: php, json

How would I structure `$array` so that when I pass it to [json_encode](http://php.net/manual/en/function.json-encode.php)

```
$output = json_encode($array);
```

the output would be:

```
$output = [
  {apples:"33" ,oranges:"22"},
  {apples:"44" ,oranges:"11"},
  {apples:"55" ,oranges:"66"},
]
```

Are there any options I need to use to get the output I need? Or is it all about how I structure my PHP array?

Comment: `json_enocde`?? you might mean `json_encode`??

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You will just need to pass an array of associative arrays to json_encode

```
$array = array (
    array(
        'apples'=>'33',
        'oranges'=>'22'
    ),
    array(
        'apples'=>'44',
        'oranges'=>'11'
    ),
    array(
        'apples'=>'55',
        'oranges'=>'66'
    )
);
```

Answer (score 3):

This should work for you:

- `[]` = array
- `{}` = object
- `key:value` = key : value

```
<?php

    $array = [
          (object)["apples" => "33", "oranges" => "22"],
          (object)["apples" => "44", "oranges" => "11"],
          (object)["apples" => "55", "oranges" => "66"],
        ];


    echo $output = json_encode($array);

?>
```

Output:

```
[
    {
        "apples": "33",
        "oranges": "22"
    },
    {
        "apples": "44",
        "oranges": "11"
    },
    {
        "apples": "55",
        "oranges": "66"
    }
]
```

Comment: Casting to object should be unnecessary, as JSON does not have indexed arrays, so any indexed PHP array will be rendered in JSON as an object anyway.

Comment: @TRiG Yes, but I wanted to show it clearly that `{}` is an object in json

Answer (score -1):

you can pass with an array of associative arrays in `json_encode($var)`.

```
$array = array (
array(
    'johan'=>'male',
    'age'=>'22'
),
array(
    'lucy'=>'female',
    'age'=>'24'
),
array(
    'donald'=>'male',
    'age'=>'28'
)
```

);